# Border on external image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there any possibility to draw a border on an external image?
For example:

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOOEO.png">
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border/

Comment: I want to have border on the image, not on a box. :P

Comment: All the same.You need to know the basics.Then you can do whatever you want to do with it !

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this? @Hatchling

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can put it in the style attribute like this for a quick solution:

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOOEO.png" style='border: 1px solid #000000'>
```

---

**Note:** Adding a border attribute to the img tag is not supported in HTML5 anymore *(credits to the heads up by Alon Eitan)*

Comment: This attribute is Obsolete since HTML5! This is not a good solution, should be implemented using CSS

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - edited the solution to reflect this as well!

Comment: I want to have border on the image, not over a box. :P

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can either use `border="5"` on the img tag itselft, Or you can use CSS

Try using:

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOOEO.png" border="5">
```

Or with CSS:

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOOEO.png" style="border: 5px solid black">
```

By using CSS you can also pick which color the border is.

Comment: I want to have border on the image, not on a box. :P

Comment: @Hatchling the white portion is part of the image i suppose.if i understand you correctly.there is nothing you can do with css in this case

Comment: @AL-zami Yes I understand, But at SO we help with problems to make solutions nothing has even been tried.

Comment: @MasterOfCoding my comment was meant for Hatchling.